# Missing stickers in a LEGO set

Tags: stickers, replacement-parts

I have a [FRIENDS set #21319](https://brickset.com/sets/21319-1/Central-Perk). It didn't come with stickers. Can someone help me purchase or get these replaced?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You should get in touch with [LEGO Customer Support](https://service.lego.com). I'm sure they will be more than happy to ship you missing sticker sheet.

If you are still looking to purchase the stickers instead, you can do so on [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogPG.asp?P=21319stk01&colorID=0).